# iOS UIImage not displaying JPEG images

Tags: ios, uiimage, png, jpeg

I'm having trouble displaying some of the images in my iOS app. I have changed some of the graphics from PNG to JPG file format and when I removed the PNG images already in the project and added the new JPGs, the simulator was still showing old PNG graphics. I ran 'clean' on the project and reset simulator's contents, and now it just does not want to load the images at all - `[UIImage imageNamed:@"filename"]` returns null.

On the other hand, if I save those graphics as PNG, and add them to the project *instead* of JPEGs, it loads them fine. But the images are photographic and PNG versions are 7-8 times larger than JPEG, so I'd really want to figure out why it won't load them.

Edit: after reviewing the documentation (for what seems like 100th time), I realized that the mistake was that I did not specify the extension. The Supported Image Formats (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) lists quite a few formats that are supported, and UIImage reference says that:

> On iOS 4 and later, if the file is in PNG format, it is not necessary to specify the .PNG filename extension.

I misread that to mean that the extension is optional in general, but if the file is not a PNG, you have to include it. So if the file is called my_image.png, then you can pass it as @"my_image" or @"my_image.png", but if you have my_image.jpg, it will only work as @"my_image.jpg".

Comment: Try deleting the `build` folder and running the app again.

Answer (score 8):

the method imageNamed: only load *.png resorce in project. Try

```
  NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"imageName"] ofType:@"jpg"];
  UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, turns out it's not that `imageNamed:` cannot load JPG images, it's that you have to explicitly specify @"filename.jpg", which I did not.

Comment: no, its the same, still cannot load that. i've had the same question of yours when i tried loading jpgs from resource.

Comment: maybe your problem was due to something different. For me `[UIImage imageNamed:@"flower.jpg"]` works perfectly fine.

Comment: Apple's docs state that leaving off the .png is simply a convenience (i.e. imageNamed: accepts .jpg extensions). Further, it is important to note that imageNamed will look in the cache first, and imageWithContentsOfFile: will not, which is a big difference.

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You see 'Supported file format' of UIImage to know some format is supported in IOS.